# Recibir un array entre componentes sin relación en Vuejs

Tags: array, vue.js, vuex, component

Estoy intentando recibir un array entre dos componentes desde `vista.vue` a `detalle.vue`.Y cuando lo reciba quiero poder verlos y luego descargarlos mediante un `CSV`. Hasta ahora he intentado mediante EventBus.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta el momento:

detalle.vue

```
`updateTaskAndService () {
  const vm = this
  vm.updateTask(vm.tkt).then((res) => {
    for (let s of vm.services) {
      vm.updateService(s).then(async (res) => {
        console.log(s, 'service')
        EventBus.$emit('updateTaskAndService', s);// Aqui estoy enviando los datos con emit
      }).catch((e) => {
        this.$toast.loading('Error actualizando Servicio', 1000)
      })
    }
    loading.hide()
    this.$toast.loading('Ticket actualizado', 1000)
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error)
  }).catch((err) => {
    this.$toast.loading('Error actualizando Ticket', 1000)
  })
},`
```

vista.vue recibir el emit:

```
created () { //Aqui recibo el emit 
   EventBus.$on('updateTaskAndService', function(s) { 
     this.s 
   })
}
```

vista.vue se ejecuta el llamado con un botón hacia el método download:

```
<c-button type="success"  @click="download" smart>
```

vista.vue en el metodo download:

```
download () {
   const serv = this.s

   for(var i=0; i<10; i++){ //aca le puse 10 para obtener si o si datos
      console.log(serv[i], "DATOS DETALLE")// Aca al recorrer el array no me muestra nada
   }
}
```

Espero que me entiendan y puedan ayudarme.

Comment: debes usar vuex

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en vista.vue no estás asignando ningún valor a tu parámetro s al recibir el emit, por lo que estará vacío en el método download:

```
    created () { //Aqui recibo el emit 
      EventBus.$on('updateTaskAndService', function(s) { 
        this.s = s //Asignamos el valor que viene en el emit al data del componente.
      })
    }
```

Un saludo.